# virtualenv install command not found on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, virtualenv, git-bash

I have a windows machine (I know, I keep trying to get the work to get me a mac)

I installed python, I installed pip

and I attempt to install virtualenv

I am using git bash (since its a nice interface that works like a linux terminal)

when I `pip install virtualenv`

```
pip install virtualenv 
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\christopherjakob\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (20.13.0)
```

same when i use `venv`

but when i try and create a virutalenv

```
virtualenv secretsManagerMCE-IMPL-LAMBDA
bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

I have been searching and I have no idea what the fix is. I have seen similar stack overflow posts but none of them discuss developing on windows

Comment: Command not found makes me think virtualenv is not in your path, from git bash can you do "where virtualenv" and make sure that folder is in your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command works on Windows:

```
python -m venv ./venv
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html